# In complex analysis, is there a special name for functions that can be written as an infinite product of linear factors?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

Let $Z$ denote a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Then some functions $f : Z \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ have the property that there exist sequences $a,b : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that for all $z \in Z$, the following expression converges absolutely, and equals $f(z).$ $$\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}(a_i z + b_i)$$

Is there a special name for such functions?

I would especially like to know the following. If $f : Z \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is such a function and $w \in \mathbb{C}$, is $f+w$ also necessarily such a function?

Comment: If the infinite product is well-defined, then you can probably rearrange to write it as $f(z) = c \prod(z + \beta_i)$. This brings it very close to the Weierstrass factorised form http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem provided that $\sum |\beta_i|^{-1} < \infty$.

Comment: And Hadamard's factorisation theorem implies that any entire function of order less than 1 can be written in your form.

Comment: @WillieWong, sorry I don't know much about complex analysis yet; what is the order of a function?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type Basically it is a measure of how fast the function grows "at infinity". The reason we need some control on the order is because functions of the type $\exp p(z)$ where $p$ is a polynomial are entire functions with no roots. Hadamard's factorisation theorem states that, roughly speaking, every entire function is a product of monomials as you have written with functions that look like $\exp p(z)$.

Comment: For more info you can consult chapter 5 of Stein and Shakarchi's _Complex Analysis_.

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks!